# How to remove parenthesis in an equation number created by \tag?

Tags: equations, align, labels

This is probably simple, but I can't figure it out. How can I remove the parentheses around a `\tag` in an `align` equation? I would like the second line (and only that) to contain `[2]` instead of `([2])`. A workaround would be to give it no label, to see the label `[2]` as part of the equation, and move it to the right text margin by hand. But how? `\hfill` does not insert space here.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a &= b \\
  c &= d \tag{[2]}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\tag*`, see p. 3 of `amsmath` documentation.

Comment: Ahh... I even used that before some time ago... Thanks, egreg!

Comment: @egreg: I made a CW anser so Marius can accept it an this question won’t stay unanswered. Hope you don’t mind :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As egreg said, use the starred version `\tag*` which is the same as `\tag` except that it does not automatically enclose the tag in parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        a + b = c \tag*{[2]}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: tag]

Comment: Does not work. `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]. \end{equation*}` Works fine with normal `\tag`. But not `\tag*{\eqref{eqlabel}}`

Comment: does not work with cleveref